# how to make 2 requests at the same time with the retrofit?

Tags: java, android, get, retrofit, retrofit2

I need to make 2 requests, first a request to ask for authorization and after this response is successful, I would then have to do the next request.

```
public void GetVariablesByFilter(){

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(serverLocalUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        final AuthToken tokenAuth = retrofit.create(AuthToken.class);

        Call<Void> call = tokenAuth.setVariableAgencia();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d("auth", response.body().toString());
                    Log.d("auth", response.toString());
                } else {
                    Log.d("auth", response.body().toString());
                    Log.d("auth", response.toString());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("auth", t.getMessage());

            }
        });
    }
```

would be these gets

```
 @GET("AppVisionService.svc/GetServerState")
    Call<ResponseBody> getServerStatus();

    @GET("AppVisionService.svc/GetVariablesByFilter?filters=$V.App.AGENCIA0001.5")
    Call<Void> setVariableAgencia();
```

I was not able to solve

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: please call other retrofit api webservice into the success response of first API